# How to import a static local json file in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying import a static local json file in my .ts like

`import json from '../../markets/localization/MktIn.json`

On run time, I get an error that module is not found. I am using webpack 4.41 and React 16.13 and json-loader 0.5.7. On my research, I see that I do not need to add any specific webpack config on versions >= 2.0 and can directly import. Can someone provide any pointers on this? I have tried couple of hours trying out all solutions from previous posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use this line of code

```js
import data from './data/data.json';
```

And also mind your relative path. Make sure it was the correct path

Here was the [detail instruction related this](https://medium.com/frontendweb/how-to-read-local-json-file-in-react-js-564125235fc7)

Hope it was help you

Thank you

Comment: Yes, the path is correct. Followed the instructions as mentioned in your link but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you confirm to us that you have write the close of apostrophe, while typing the path to the line code?

Answer (score 0):

javascript native can import js and json file。so you should input the wrong path，review your path ？

Comment: It is not an issue with the path